A question that has a disjunction in it
I need your help to analyse and point out whether this question doesn't has an answer or not. I've been arguing with my master coach that there is something wrong with this question, but they don't seem to see it or perhaps, it is I who didn't see it where the mistake.
This is the question:
The quadratic function $x^2 + x - 6$ has an intersect point with line $x=2$. What is the statement that is true if [$P$ is defined by the value of either root of $x^2 + x - 6$ ], [$Q$ = the abscissa of the intersect point].
The options:
A. $P > Q$
B. $P < Q$
C. $P = Q$
D. We couldn't determine the relation between $P$ and $Q$
My master coach said that it would be $D$ as the answer, since it's not consistent, since the roots of the quadratic function are $-3$ and $2$. He said, $P < Q$ i.e. $-3<2$ (correct) and $P = Q$ i.e. $2=2$ (correct). Since they're not consistent, thus the answer is $D$.
The graph is shown here:

My opinion
The roots of any quadratic equation would always be $2$ i.e. $\left(x_1 \, x_2\right)$ (assuming it doesn't matter whether the roots are real or complex numbers), I believe. That means we now say it, it's either $P < Q$ or $P = Q$ (disjunction). Since it is a disjunction, wouldn't this question have $2$ correct answers as well? I.e. $B$ and $C$ are correct, right? I believe, we can't choose $D$, since the relation CAN be determined. As Mr. Naïm Favier said in the comment, what if the equation has $0$ root? I'm sorry, the question is about the "value" of either root and not the number of roots. So, I'm assuming if there were a similar question, and they put $D$ as an answer, wouldn't $P$ are complex numbers? Of course it is, because $<, >$ doesn't work in complex numbers right?
Please explain it to me whether I had an incorrect thinking. Thank you so much in advance.

This question makes little sense. $P$ is "defined by the roots" of the quadratic? What if there are 0 or 2? If $Q$ is the $x$-coordinate of the intersection of a curve with the line $x = 2$, then $Q = 2$ by definition. What does this have to do with the roots?

@NaïmFavier What do you mean? They are numbers, of course the roots will have a relation with $Q$, regarding your case. Then $P$ is either $0$ or $2$ right? Since $Q=2$, isn't $P=Q$ or $P<Q$?

@NaïmFavier you might be mixed up with "2" as the abscissa and "2" as the number of the roots. I might use the word "value" (please do apologise my English). I'm talking about the relation of the value P and Q

Given any function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique intersection point between the graph of $f$ and the vertical axis $x = 2$. The coordinates of the intersection point are $(2, f(2))$, so its abscissa is $2$. Please reflect on this and edit your question if this is not what you meant.

If P is the point (0,2) and Q is the point (0,2), then P=Q. If P is the point (0,-3), then  P $\ne$ Q.

If P is the "generic" description of the intersection point of that specific curve, then either P=Q or P $\ne$Q... that holds for every pair of points whatever, and thus is quite useless.

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA P is not generic. P is specific and Q is specific. Well, to put it simple, P is -3 or 2 and Q is 2, what is the relation of P and Q, that's the question. It's crystal clear to me that P can be less or the same as Q. I.e. -3<2 or 2=2.

If that's the question, then what's the point of the whole exposition with the quadratic function and whatnot? We have $-3 < 2$ and $2 = 2$, hence if $P = -3 \lor P = 2$ then $P < 2 \lor P = 2$, i.e. $P \leq 2$.

P is a name and a name is ... a name. Thus, either P is the positive root or it os the negative one. If instead we use a "concept" denoting one of the roots, a concept may be instantiated by more than one object: apostle of Christ.

Let's not use hazardous analogies. $P$ denotes a real number such that $P = -3 \lor P = 2$, i.e. an element of ${-3, 2}$. Formally, $\forall P \in {-3, 2}. P < 2 \lor P = 2$.

@NaïmFavier . That's the implication of the question. I think you're mistaken. Sorry. Roots cannot simultaneously solve for one equation. You can't substitute $x$ with two numbers at the same time, thus you have to choose one of them. I,e. That's the concept of disjunction. Or.

When you write stuff like "wouldn't $P$ are complex numbers? Of course it is..." you should expect downvotes. If you can't take the trouble to express yourself in comprehensible language, what do you expect?

@GerryMyerson FYI I did write that after I received downvotes. Now I'm asking. A person who doesn't come from English speaking country asking a question like this. I should say it's normal. That is why here exist moderators. If they don't do what they should do i.e. editing the question or clarifying my question or helping to make my question understandable, then what use of them of this site? Only if I were rich would I pay a smart mathematician to answer my queries. I believe this site is to help people receiving answers for their problems. Or is it a site that only downvotes questions?

You have a lot to learn about this website. First, moderators have a lot of responsibilities on this website, but editing  and clarifying questions are not among them. Second, the official reason this site is here is to build a repository of good questions and answers. Helping people to receive answers for their problems is only an occasional (but welcome!) side effect of the site's main mission. Third, while I feel there are people here who are too quick to cast unexplained downvotes, this is also a site that has helped tens of thousands of people to learn mathematics. (continued)

(continued) You're seeing only the bad; there is an awful lot of good here.

@GerryMyerson It is certainly not what you have just written. 2 closed votes have been casted. I mean, is it too difficult to just go back to my problem and answer my question? I could even edit the question if you didn't understand my incomprehensible language. Just point out which one. Is that too difficult to do? Or are you just commenting randomly to discourage one who is desperately looking for answers?

It seems to me that your question has been answered by the users who have posted comments. I have pointed out one place where your language is incomprehensible, and you have done nothing about it. I am not commenting randomly, and I am not trying to discourage you; I am commenting constructively, and trying to encourage you to give up your misconceptions about the way this website works.

Maybe I can summarize the discussion.
I think we all agree that $Q=2$.
Also, that the roots of $x^2+x-6$ are $x=2$ and $x=-3$.
The problem is in the statement,
$$
P {\rm\ is\ defined\ by\ the\ value\ of\ either\ root\ of\ }x^2+x-6.
$$
This is a very peculiar way to define something. I think the most reasonable interpretation of this sentence is that $P$ is either $2$ or $-3$, but we cannot tell which.
Now we are given four options, and the way multiple choice questions go, we are asked to choose exactly one of the options.
Option A is clearly false.
Option B could be false, since $P$ could be $2$.
Option C could be false, since $P$ could be $-3$.
That leaves us with option D, which is true; we don't know enough about $P$ to determine the relation between $P$ and $Q$.
End of discussion.

Thank you very much for your answer. There is, however, a little doubt in me. I hope you could help me once more. Regarding the option $B$. Based on inclusive disjunction, if one of two statements is correct thus it's correct. I.e. $P<Q$ is correct, or $P=Q$ that is to say $P\nless Q$ (True or False makes it True). That's the idea of my main question. It goes the same with the option C. $P=Q$ or $P<Q$ which is the same thing as $P≠Q$. (True or False, makes it True). I hope you would point out my mistaken thinking. Thanks in advance.

OK, let's clear away all the clutter, and put it like this: Suppose $Q=2$, and suppose we know $P$ is either $2$ or $-3$, but we have no way of knowing which. Is it true that $P<Q$? I think the only possible answer is, we don't know. We don't have enough information to decide whether $P<Q$. We don't have enough information to decide whether $P=Q$. We know that one of those is true, but we don't know which one. We don't know enough to determine the relation between $P$ and $Q$. I think you're trying to interpret the question as, "which option(s) could be true", (continued)

(continued) when it's meant to be interpreted as "which option must be true".

Thanks. I actually asked a similar question that has a different answer as I've concluded from your answer. Please see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4948832/664855 . Perhaps if I may, I would ask "what's more information I have to have to be able to decide the relation if it's said that I don't have enough information?"

In the $P$ and $Q$ question that we have been discussing, any information that lets you decide the value of $P$ will do. If you're told $P$ is negative, that's enough additional information. If you're told $P$ is an even integer, that's enough information. $P^2>7$ would be enough information.
